# Application error: Heroku, Request Timed Error is been shown

Tags: python, heroku, web-scraping, web-deployment

I have deployed my web application into Heroku. Everything was perfectly done. I didn't get any errors while deploying. Now, when I open the link of my application, the first page works fine. But when click on "submit" button on my page, it loads for some time and then shows "Application Error".

Then I went to the logs location in my dashboard. I got these log files.

```
    2018-04-13T04:34:48.194083+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-13 04:34:48 +0000] [38] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 38
2018-04-13T04:41:25.473230+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=85a22384-f24b-4bcd-9d50-757ad97f0963 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=902 protocol=http
2018-04-13T04:41:25.473331+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.67.146.6 - - [13/Apr/2018:04:41:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 741 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
2018-04-13T04:41:25.815669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=fe0bf28d-21c6-49b2-8a45-16addc227825 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=1586 protocol=http
2018-04-13T04:41:25.815700+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.67.146.6 - - [13/Apr/2018:04:41:25 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://gitam-results.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
2018-04-13T04:41:26.180053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=8ab0bbe2-b7bc-46a7-a5af-dea0e55bf408 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=386 protocol=http
2018-04-13T04:41:26.180263+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.67.146.6 - - [13/Apr/2018:04:41:26 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "http://gitam-results.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
2018-04-13T04:42:02.010695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/results/" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=5f0c2b03-c84e-41f9-8cc4-e37d5d661587 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2018-04-13T04:42:02.845826+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-13 04:42:02 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9)
2018-04-13T04:42:03.859224+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-13 04:42:03 +0000] [48] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 48
2018-04-13T05:10:23.288981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=664a9114-cbe5-4c2d-8451-415dae319256 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=902 protocol=http
2018-04-13T05:10:23.285215+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.239.176 - - [13/Apr/2018:05:10:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 741 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
2018-04-13T05:10:23.591700+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=b86bd2e3-be99-4cbe-852f-77c35dffbf92 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1586 protocol=http
2018-04-13T05:10:23.589416+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.239.176 - - [13/Apr/2018:05:10:23 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://gitam-results.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
2018-04-13T05:10:59.469518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/results/" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=dc79befc-0a0e-45c1-b0f7-e512d24efed2 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2018-04-13T05:10:59.619178+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-13 05:10:59 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:48)
2018-04-13T05:11:00.635704+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-13 05:11:00 +0000] [58] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 58
2018-04-13T05:13:09.067854+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/results/" host=gitam-results.herokuapp.com request_id=c4cdf07c-c9b3-4579-a5ac-09e6868c45b6 fwd="49.207.27.49" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2018-04-13T05:13:09.846659+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-13 05:13:09 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:38)
2018-04-13T05:13:10.863667+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-13 05:13:10 +0000] [68] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68
```

But when I run it from local system, it is working fine. What would be the reason for this? I am performing scraping on my college site. Is that stopping my app to work?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will display the "Application error" page for requests which are taking more than 30 seconds. Even though heroku displays error page to the client, the request will still be processed by your application in the backgroud. This is heroku's default behaviour.

Quote from heroku devcenter article on how to workaround this behaviour.

`If your server requires longer than 30 seconds to complete a given request, we recommend moving that work to a background task or worker to periodically ping your server to see if the processing request has been finished. This pattern frees your web processes up to do more work, and decreases overall application response times.`

Source : [Heroku Request Timeouts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)

Comment: But the request takes maximum of 15 sec. Does heroku free server support pinging to other sites?